# featured image problem with custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I created a new custom post type based on the code provided by the wordpress codex. But when I try to set a featured image it returns and shows -1 in the featured image box instead of the images.

I checked in the function that sets the featured image and it looks like it doesn't pass the check to see if I'm allowed to edit the post ( current_user_can('edit_post', $postID) )

However when I check somewhere in my plugin (I'm adding meta boxes in that particular page) with the same function it shows that I have the right to edit the page.

Anyone an idea why it is causing a problem with the featured image?

Comment: Are you using any plugins on your site?

Comment: @josuha yes, that particular custom is inside a plugin itself

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking that everything is good with the image being saved to the CPT.  Inside the loop...

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
<?php echo $url ?>
```

This will hopefully echo the image's URL... if that is working then you probably have a problem with the loop conflicting with something else on the page.